# Swagger codegen overrides query parameter with a header parameter that has the same name

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I have a swagger definition that has a query and a header that share the same name:

```
parameters:
  qry_param:
    name: appid
    in: query
    required: true
    type: string
  hdr_param:
    name: appid
    in: header
    required: false
    type: string
...
paths:
  '/some/path/here':
    post:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/hdr_param'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/qry_param'
```

When I try to generate a client with `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` only request header is generated for this parameter.

What can I do to generate both?